# cardinality of certain infinite subset of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

in a game of basketball, each throw gives you either 3 or 5 points.

(a) how many scores are impossible?

(b) Replace 3,5 by a,b, when is the total number of impossible scores finite?

(c) Suppose we knows that the total number of impossible scores is exactly 65, determine a,b.

For part a, i attempt to compute the cardinality $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{3x+5y: x,y \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$, but since both sets are infinite, i have no clue how to compute. I know the diophantine equation $3x+5y=a$ always has integer solution since $(3,5)=1$, but if we restrict to positive integer solutions, i don't know how to count the number of solutions.

And for part b,c, I have no idea how to start. Please give a help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $gcd(a,b)=1$ , then every number larger than or equal to $(a-1)(b-1)$ can be written as a nonnegative integer combination of $a,b$ . This means that every number larger than :

```
         $(3-1)(5-1)=8$
```

can be written as  a combination of $3$ and $5$.

Proof: 
i)$8=3+5$
ii)$9=3+3+3$
iii) $10=5+5$

So we have found a complete set $mod3$ ; every other number $n>10$ can be obtained by adding a multiple of 3 to one of these 3, depending on its congruence class, e.g. $n=100$. is $1(mod3)$ , (just like $10$ above is), so that $100=10+90=5+5+3(30)$

b)The number of scores will be finite when $gcd(a,b)=1$ , by above argument; every
number larger-or-equal-to $(a-1)(b-1)$ can be written as a non-negative integer combination of  $a,b$

Notice what will happen if $gcd(a,b)>1$ if we have a,b with $gcd(a,b)>1 $; then every combination will be a multiple of d, so that we will miss out on all the non-multiples of $d$ , e.g., if we have $a=6$, $b=9$ , then $6r+9t=3(2s+3t)$ will necessarily be a multiple of $3$

c) We want a,b with $(a-1)(b-1)=66$ , and $gcd(a,b)=1$ . You have that $a=12$ and $b=7$ works.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, then either $A$ is finite or there is a bijection between $A$ and $\Bbb N$.

For the second part you need a condition on $a$ and $b$ so $\Bbb N\setminus\{ax+by\mid x,y\in\Bbb N\}$ is a finite set. For example, $a=1, b=0$ is such a case.

Finally the third case asks you to find out what are $a$ and $b$ if you are told that there are only $65$ values you cannot write as $ax+by$.

Comment: then for part a, the answer is 0? because obviously $A$ is infinite. Then how is part (c)? Infinite-Infinite=65... I am very confused with the "size of infinity"...

Comment: In the case of the integers there is really just one size of infinity, but the question here is about the complement. It's asking you what would be the complement of the infinite set, given conditions on $a$ and $b$. Sometimes the complement of an infinite set is infinite (e.g. even and odds) and sometimes it's a finite set (e.g. the empty set and everything). But as for "size", you don't need to be confused, there is only one possible size of an infinite set of natural numbers.